# JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly in Groovy

Tags: linux, shell, groovy

I install groovy in ubuntu and when i run groovy command in terminal i saw the bellowing error:

```
groovy: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly, can 
not execute: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java
```

what should i do to solve this?

Comment: As a fair warning: in the past the groovy version you could install from the ubuntu repos where extremly outdated (around 1.8).  You are usually better off using sdkman to install it.

Answer (score 20):

Updating `JAVA_HOME` or `PATH` environment variables is ok for individual users, but to fix it system-wide, just create the missing symlink. For me, it went like this:

```
$ groovy --version
groovy: JAVA_HOME not defined, can't execute: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java

$ cd /usr/lib/jvm
$ ls -log
lrwxrwxrwx 1   20 Nov  1 14:17 java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-8-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 7 4096 Feb  3 02:36 java-8-openjdk-amd64

$ sudo ln -s java-8-openjdk-amd64/ default-java
$ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 2.4.8 JVM: 1.8.0_151 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

Answer (score 3):

You should take the whole directory where java is installed and also add java home in PATH variable, for example:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

For verification purpose you can also run below commands,

```
echo $PATH
java -version
```